# Google Search Console displays errors with ":fast_forward" added to URLs

Tags: google-search-console, url, crawl-errors

I have two webpages and their URLs are like:

`https://example.com/videoCenter`

`https:/example.com/register`

But today I found that indexing errors show that Google had crawled URLs like:

`https://example.com/register:fast_forward`

and

`https://example.com/vieoCenter:fast_forward`.

Both of these have `:fast_forward` added to them, but we don't have these URLs in our site, or have posted them on other websites.

Can anyone tell me why indexing errors in Google Search Console show this? How can I fix them?

Comment: It appears you also asked this over at Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066868/why-the-url-occur-https-xxxfast-forward-in-google-search-console) too. Please do not [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) questions to more than one Stack Exchange site since that spreads answers out among them. Also, please use the generic domain "example.com" instead of URLs to your site, since that can be viewed as self-promotional by the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these pages don't exist and Google tries to crawl them, you should find them in the the Google Search console report for pages that are not found. If you click on the link in that report, Google should show you where they found the links.

You should check your analytics tool to see if you get a lot of traffic to the pages. If you do, fix the error on your site it that is the source.  If the source is another site, create 301 redirects. If there's not much traffic, you can ignore them.

[Google also provide recommendations for handling 404 errors](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35120?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, it's a pretty useful solution for me.